# How to create a package in Xamarin Studio 5 for Mono.Mac application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

Xamarin Studio 4 has a corresponding option in a [project options](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6814/create-installer-package-pkg-but-that-pkg-does-not-do-anything-useful#latest).

How to create a package (*.pkg file) in a Xamarin Studio 5 ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Michael Hutchinson from the [Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21350/how-to-create-a-package-in-xamarin-studio-5-for-mono-mac-application):

> This is only supported for Xamarin.Mac projects, since the pkg
>   installers contain an embedded copy of the Mono runtime so that they
>   can be distributed on the Mac App Store.
>
> You can either migrate your MonoMac project to Xamarin.Mac, or
>   manually create a package from the .app which will depend on a system
>   installation of Mono.